# Huge Repo even after shallow clone

Tags: git

I have a space constraint on my machine and went for a shallow clone of a Repo but it still almost equals the size of the Repo with regular clone

Size of the Contents - 6 GB 
Size of .git Folder - 5 GB

```
    (99% of it is being used by
       .git/objects/pack/pack-4e659f68d88eb0f3611923febff213649b669fbd.pack)
```

*Syntax used to shallow clone:*
git clone --depth 1

Not exactly sure how I can bring down the Repo size to closely match the size of the contents without any history.

Comment: What form of URL did you use when you made the shallow clone?

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger  git clone --depth 1 h t t p s://Company.visualstudio.com/ProjectA/_git/TestRepo

Comment: Hmm... never tried to shallow a repo directly from TFS. It might not support it properly.  Can you try using a `file://` URL to re-clone (with `--depth=1`) from a local clone?  (When you do this, it *has* to be a `file://` URL, not a simple local path, or `--depth` won't work.)

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger thanks will give it a try

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger No..It didnot work.

Comment: In your question, you note the repo size as the evidence that shallowing the repo didn't work; but I can find no reason the shallowing itself should fail (even directly from TFS, which I've sense tested successfully).  So I have a theory.  In your clone, can you show the output of `git rev-list --all`?

Comment: Also, when you quote "size of git folder" and "size of contents": does the "size of contents" include the .git folder, or is that "5GB in the git folder, and 6GB in the work tree outside the git folder"?

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger wow..when I execute 'git rev-list --all' I get a list of 470 SHAs...The repository that I am working used to be in TFS and we migrated it to GIT using a tool called 'git-tf'.Do you think that might have to do with this?

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger 5GB in git folder and 6gb in the work tree outside git folder

Comment: Well, that does suggest the clone isn't shallow -- or else that it has 470 branches in it and was created with the `--no-single-branch` flag, but that doesn't sound right.  I'm puzzled why the shallowing command isn't working, but I'm also not sure it matters; if the work tree is 6GB then a single commit could still result in a huge repo.

Comment: If you create a new clone, delete its .git folder (`rm -r .git`), and then `git init` and `git add .` and `git commit`, how big is the .git folder created by doing that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143908/discussion-between-rajscubicle-and-mark-adelsberger).